# PhpStorm align arguments of consecutive function calls

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is this possible?

Currently:

```
$foo->foobar($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
$foo->foobar($argument1, $argument2, $argument3)
$foo->foobar($string1, $int1, $bool1)
```

What I want is:

```
$foo->foobar($arg1,      $arg2,      $arg3);
$foo->foobar($argument1, $argument2, $argument3)
$foo->foobar($string1,   $int1,      $bool1)
```

Particularly useful for PDO `bindValue` assignments. I've tried most of the alignment options in Function/Constructor call arguments.

Comment: I've never seen that, but also would not like it. That should be requested as a feature in YouTrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible / PhpStorm does not have this particular formatting functionality.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12233 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress. So far it does not have much interest from the community.

---

P.S. Perhaps one of the supported *external formatters* can do it (PHP CS Fixer or PHP Code Beautifier and Fixer)?

Comment: This was requested 11 years ago, so unlikely to be implemented. Thanks anyway for taking the time to respond.